# Which rails command am I runnning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, initialization

I'm trying to discover which rails command am I running on a initializer module like this:

```
module MyModule
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "my_module.configure_rails_initialization" do |app|
        puts "RAILS #{s} RUNNING!"
        #do something with ze app
    end
  end
end
```

The possible commands are: ***generate, console, server, dbconsole, runner***

I've read initialization guide at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

But didn't found how to get which command at initialization time.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer of your question but a workaround I've used.
I needed to know if "rails console" was started.

I simply tested if the console class was defined:

```
puts "Running console modes... " if defined?( Rails::Console )
```

You can also use this option for Rails::Server

For dbconsole, runner and generate the solution above doesn't work

Comment: Wow, that's almost an year ago but it works... I thought I would need to add a constant to Rails Gem but this way is good enough!